# Routes in react app are not working when deploying to cloud run

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have this react app, and everything is working fine, but, I'm having problems with my routes when deploying...

This is how I'm setting up my routes

Index.tsx (Here, i have BrowserRouter)

```
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { CssBaseline } from '@mui/material'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

import { storeConfig } from './application/store'
import App from './presentation/App'

render(
  <>
    <CssBaseline />
    <Provider store={storeConfig}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
  </>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

App.tsx (And here, I have my routes explicitly)

```
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'

import Layout from './components/layout/LayoutHero'
import Error from './website/404'
import Auth from './website/Auth'
import Home from './website/Home'
import Map from './website/Map'
import ProtectedDeniedAccess from './components/atoms/protected_routes/ProtectedDeniedAccess'
import ProtectedAuth from './components/atoms/protected_routes/ProtectedAuth'

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route element={<ProtectedAuth />}>
        <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
          <Route index element={<Home />} />

          <Route path="recogida_georreferenciada/:pickup" element={<Map />} />

          <Route element={<ProtectedDeniedAccess />}>
            <Route path="acceso_denegado" element={<Error />} />
          </Route>

          <Route path="*" element={<Error />} />
        </Route>
      </Route>

      <Route path="/auth" element={<Auth />} />
    </Routes>
  )
}

export default App
```

And, in local, everything works great, but when I deploy to cloud and try to re-load the page or go to a route that does not exist so it can re-direct the user to /404, and other stuff, I usually get this message.

[image]

Just two questions:

Why is this happening?
How can I fix it ?

Comment: Read over the [CRA deployment](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/) docs for a relevant section for where/how you are deploying your app to a server. The gist is that you generally need to redirect all page requests to your index.html file so the app is returned and RRD can render the correct component for the path.

Answer (score 0):

Put exact keyword in Route tag, it might take you to exact route and rest any url will go to  component.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is API error. Check your Google API.